# Interacting with Hidden Fields and Actions with Javascript

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to figure out how to get values back and forth between an external javascript library and the Acumatica back end.

Currently I have 2 fields that are hidden (set to hidden on the PXUIField Attribute) and I am picking up their values successfully as follows:

```
    function doSomething() {
        var url = px_alls['txtUrl'].value;
        var clientId = px_alls['txtClientID'].value;

    }
```

However I am not having the same luck setting a hidden fields values and then posting the data to the back end in this way:

```
    client.on('someEvent', (data) => {
        px_alls['txtId'].value = data.id;
        Save();
    })
```

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks
-Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading form fields from px_alls works fine but I was not able to automate saving.

I use action callback to send the values from JavaScript to an action defined in the Graph.

```
var ds = px_alls['ds'];
ds.executeCallback('TestAction', 'parameter value');
```

Then In the graph you can use the parameter value to update the document:

```
public PXAction<PrimaryDAC> TestAction;

[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test Action")]
public virtual IEnumerable testAction(PXAdapter adapter)
{
  string parameterValue = adapter.CommandArguments;

  // Update document here with parameter value

  return adapter.Get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hugues! Would it be possible to pass back multiple parameters?

Comment: It's a string so you can pass pretty much anything in there. It could be JSON or any type of formatted value.

Comment: Right... admittedly did not think of json haha. thanks!